# php count array rows with same id

Tags: php, arrays, csv, row, counter

Hello everybody I have a script that loops an array that put data in a CSV file, i need to count the rows with same ID.

this is my scritpt that loops the array and put it in a csv file for export.

```
public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
{
    if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
    {
        //one ready for export product
        $readyForExport = array();
        //put in correct sort order
        foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
        {
            $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
            $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);
        }
        //write into csv line by line
        fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
    }
}
```

I've tried to use :

```
$numero_riga = array_count_values($readyForExport);

$readyForExport['numero_riga'] = $numero_riga;
```

but it does not print any correct value in the csv file meabe because it is a multi dimensional array, you can see the csv export in the text and screenshot below:

```
ID row_number
```

```
198 Array
199 Array
200 Array
200 Array
201 Array
201 Array
201 Array
201 Array
202 Array
202 Array
203 Array
203 Array
203 Array
204 Array
204 Array
204 Array
204 Array
204 Array
205 Array
205 Array
205 Array
206 Array
207 Array
207 Array
208 Array
209 Array
```

[csv export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejQbe.png)

The result have to be like this in the text and screenshot below you can see a column that counts the rows with same ID.

```
ID row_number
```

```
176 1
177 1
177 2
178 1
178 2
179 1
179 2
180 1
181 1
181 2
182 1
182 2
183 1
184 1
184 2
185 1
185 2
186 1
186 2
186 3
```

[correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhCFV.png)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Edited whit suggestions from scaisEdge but now the csv export acts in a strange way. I paste screenshot here [csv strange behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11uTf.png)

EDIT

now I'm using this code whit the help of scaisEdge, i think we are close to the solution.

```
             $cnt_row = 0;
             $match_id = -1;
            //put in correct sort order
            foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
            {
                if ( $value['id_order'] == $match_id){
                   $cnt_row++;
                } else {
                   $cnt_row =1;
                   $match_id  = $value['id_order'];
                }
                //$value['num_row'] = $cnt_row;
                print_r($cnt_row);
                $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
                $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);

            }

            $readyForExport['num_row'] = $cnt_row;
```

i paste the screenshot of the actual result here: [partially correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fEWn.png) you can see that now is printing some values in the correct column but is prints " 4 " all the time...

Comment: update your question and add  a simple data sample (as text, not image) and the expected  result

Comment: thanks for interest I've edited the question. hope now it is properly written

Comment: you want add  to each row the relative number of sequence respect the id ?  ..  you have a foreach for manager the code  .?? .. update you question and add the for each that manage  the  result

Comment: thanks again i've added the for each code above

Comment: yes i need to print in the csv row the relative number of sequence respect the id

Comment: You question is not clear to me .. how the data sample is related  to the code  ?.. $value is a single row?  and what mean $readyForExport[$value] ??  is an array for all the rows ??

Comment: yes $readyForExport[$value] is the array for all the row , the variable $value contains the value of related to the colum in this case we need to coung the rows of the $readyForExport['id_order'] Many thanks

Comment: answer  updated  with a suggestion  ..  hope is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
class Yourclass {
    private $counter = null;

    public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
    {
            if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
            {
                    //one ready for export product
                    $readyForExport = array();

                    //put in correct sort order
                    foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
                    {
                            $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
                            $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);
                    }

                    $this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']] = (!empty($this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']])) ? ++$this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']] : 1;
                    $readyForExport['orderLine'] = $this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']];

                    fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to put the line data in a variable before printin in csv file with fputcsv function can we modify the foreach line counter to put in a $readyForExport['num_row'] array field that can be printend in csv column ?

Comment: I need to append another colum before it prints it into csv file because there is more code the eleaborates the $readyForExport[$value] data. must modify the fputcsv less as possible so i need to calculate the row number and put it in a $readyForExport[orderLine] field that prints into fputcsv. many thanks

Comment: need somthing like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359589/php-count-array-rows-with-same-id The one from Nigel Ren

Comment: Sorry this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367509/php-count-occurences-of-an-array-field-and-increment-the-value-of-another-field from Nigel Ren the last answer . I need to put the foreach loop you made in a variable that wil be printend in fputcsv . many thanks

Comment: meabe something like this: $readtForExport['orderLine'] = $counts[$value['id_order']]['rows'];

Comment: still unsupported operand. i need to put the foreach counter of the rows in array field like this  $readtForExport['orderLine'] = $counter and not to modify fputcsv . Thank for being patient...

Comment: my script should look like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61b28f463f7d5cdc3856bab14d43e57dda2c8060 with the custom code for your counter. This code is clear but it prints 1 all the time in the csv column. just modify the foreach of the row counter and we have done. tried to modify that code but still prints 1 all the time. many many thanks !!

Comment: yeah thats true but you can read the array fields and wite them in csv line by line thats what the script does I need to make a foreach to count the lines that have same order ID and put them into an array field that would be printed into a csv column ad other data is in array $allexportedfields then moved $readyForExport ... can you modify Nigel Rens code ?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b96842411cc0d50ac9280301a3d6b73bcded50e

Comment: There is $readyForExport you dont need to modify the fputcsv function we need to clicle the array, count the row compared to order id and put them into $readyForExport so we can print all data line by line in csv

Comment: an example like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/492b94749820dbf080fc247223f6ef70a2bde546

Comment: Same thing, I have already given you both example. You either process your fputcvs while you create the new array. Then you don't need another looping. OR, you use the array I created in the sample and loop line by line for fputcvs

Comment: dont know how to put it in my code you haveto excuse me... my entire script is like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f20f3c6914444137f241bed3529ae0b39baaf29 so you can see that there is lot of data processing. I only need to count the rows comparing id_order and put them into a $readyForExpor['orderLine'] array field so my fputcsv print all line by line...

Comment: id_order is correct I don't see any other assumptions... can you check againg ?

Comment: I don't see any problem by looking at it. Please use print_r to examine the array $readyForExport

Comment: meabe we should return $value['orderLine'] = $counter[$value['id_order']]; outside the foreach loop ? I've seen this kind of malformed csv some days ago with other code examples

Comment: i've added this but prints no value in csv colum // Add in the orderLine column
                $readtForExport['orderLine'] = $counter[$value['id_order']];

Comment: Can you first explain why $readyForExport['product_price'] = $newPrice; is not inside the foreach loop? if $readyForExport['product_price'] is not inside the loop, how to you expect $readyForExport['orderLine'] to be updated with count? To avoid this confusion in the future, it would be great if you can provide a sample array with expected output also in an array format

Comment: i put print_r from $readyForExport http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df4a6397672524cf9d605bcd02a969c6e1d9a8f0 you can see the array come malformed

Comment: $readyForExport['product_price'] = $newPrice; is the result processed from $allexportfields array putted line by line in $readyForExpor thats why is not in the loop

Comment: so you execute fputToFile with a foreach loop? I am lost. Coz your fputcsv in not in a loop

Comment: Dont know why but you can see it works all ready without the mods for the row counting ...

Comment: Coz the count is in the loop and your fputcsv is not. You should process your other columns like the answer I provided. At this point, I would suggest you to try to understand my script and incorporate the rest of your code to it. Since no answer is accepted. You may add extra update to your question to give a better picture. Make sure your original code is working. I will try my best to help if I have a better picture

Comment: Can we try to execute a foreach loop with $readyForExport[] array and process the results ? $readyForExport[] contains all the data from $allexportfields

Comment: My original code is workin well without the row count mods ad I was saing... If you see I also made a foreach loop just some lines more before the fputcsv where I rearrange the $readyForExport fields, thats why I say we can make another foraeach loop to count this mothaf** rows, but Im still a rookie you have to escuse me and I have to thank you a lot, now im goin to paste you a screenshot from the csv output

Comment: here is my csv export with some null colum and the one that waits for the order row number that now is empty https://ibb.co/fcoguc

Comment: Try this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0f0087d728594cae173cef932f3c4cad5f588283 BEFORE passing it to your fputToFile

Comment: Ill try it asap now im going to paste you the var_dump of $readyForExport

Comment: Check var_dump of $readyForExport http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/855fa142458a8235ec8c91fe84ff7214e3460a84

Comment: mysort outside fputToFile gives me syntax error, unexpected '$allexportfields' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: that code outside gives syntax error, then i putted it inside fputToFile without the declaration of function script does not gives error but csv is empy...

Comment: Sample here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8dcc2aa7ff9c4da30bd8632075521543d3e19b59 by the way I'm testing your new code asap

Comment: with this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/324cabbbd1462a65dfebabfcb794c434e4cee8a5 gives me [PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file :/var/www/unisit_ecommerce/modules/advancedexport/advancedexport.php:
syntax error, unexpected '$allexportfields' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) . so I've commented         //$allexportfields = $this->mysort($allexportfields, 'id_order');

        print_r($allexportfields); resulting in no errors but ofcourse no data in csv colum for row count

Comment: You cannot call your the method like that. Since you call your fputToFile in a foreach loop, you will need to process your array before passing to fputToFile. Which means you will have to call mysort outside the fputToFile. Check your code and try to implement like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0840be46ca78a4636f560618778bd13b27393790

Comment: It gives me syntax error because all functions are inside a class, I suppose, so we have to modify mysort function to read $allexportfields as directly as is done in fputToFile, many many thanks I will try and wait for your response

Comment: As I said, you cannot rely on fputToFile to do the job. Sorry, it has to be outside the method and you have to modify the class coz fputToFile is called from a loop externally

Comment: Done this meabe coul be right ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0675504b91d1284238b9b90e1f9e1bf45c545286

Comment: Malformed csv result ... Im going to pastebin all the class file cause we are very close to the point

Comment: Here we are patience seems infinite... https://pastebin.com/7ximHV3c meabe you can help modify the entire class and finish, hope so many thanks...

Comment: sincere hugs ! I will test your mods as soon as possible

Comment: Im sorry to inform that nothing happens the column inside csv for the line count is empty...

Comment: the alert system is useful anyway $readyForExport['orderLine']); seems to remain null https://pastebin.com/1n4BfSsg

Comment: Modified like this and the result is 13 all the time http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48a4cbef4c0a49bacf4d6a1648347bc01ac5a736 I've also think there some small mistakes, from $counter to $count object in your previous code

Comment: I've corrected the errors $counter/$count and commented the print_r commands and nows seems to be working correctly, Many Many Thanks !!

Comment: Glad to know. I have update my answer to reflect the solution.

Comment: Please delete those unrelated comments and keep this history short for other to understand better. Accept the answer so we know this post is closed. Possibily add some notes to your original question and make it more education to future readers.'

Comment: Hello once again I have added a custom field to the customer object, so I have modified the table and added the possibility to edit this custom field from Prestashop backend. I need to fetch the new data from the new custom field and put it in the field 'id_customer' . https://pastebin.com/e1s7j4SH Look at line 203 and 1273. thanks for all done since now!

Comment: Please create a new post for newly added issue and this time make sure you have sample array and expected output.

Comment: Thanks your help is priceless Michael I've made a new post as you suggested here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487896/fetch-data-from-prestashop-custom-field

Comment: Tried to make another MySql query inside the code but nothing happens, please help.

Comment: I've tried many ways please check the code there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487896/fetch-data-from-prestashop-custom-field

Comment: Michael are you free to talk ?

Comment: Michael please help im stuck since 4 days ago with this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507474/put-mysql-query-result-in-array-inside-a-class im unable to move the external array of query result to the inside of the class

Answer (score 0):

you should check when the id_order change   not the number of the elements in array

```
public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
{
    if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
    {
        //one ready for export product
        $readyForExport = array();
        //put in correct sort order
        $cnt_row = 0;
        $match_id = '';
        //cicle through the array
        foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
        {
            if ( $match_id == $value['id_order']){
               $cnt_row++;
            } else {
               $cnt_row =1;
               $match_id  = $value['id_order'];
            }
            $value['num_row'] = $cnt_row;
            $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
            $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);

        }
        //write into csv line by line
        fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found some small errors, there are 2 semicolon missing, nothing so hard to correct :-)

Comment: answer  update d.. missing ; after $value['num_row']

Comment: now it results in a strange behaviour the csv is malformed... I have edited the code like this : $value['num_row'] = (string)$cnt_row; beause of the UTF-8 forced below

Comment: i don't understand your comment .. with the (string) conversion is solved  or you have problem??

Comment: unfortunately not ... but I've tought that was the problem... I wanted to paste a screenshot of the csv but don't know how to put it in comment

Comment: Edited as you suggested and inserted the screenshot, many thanks

Comment: have you added a proper fileld for the  column name in the first row.. ?  and you $value is an array of fileds or is a a CSV string?

Comment: $value is an array of fields, can we add the field and eliminate the first row ? for the result the first row is useless

Comment: you can try .., looking to the img seems that the columns are shifted  so i think there some diffrence between the number of column expected and the real number  of columns

Comment: I added some fields outside the foreach loop but this has not affected the csv. how can i push the num_row variable outside the foreach ? tried like this:   $readyForExport['num_row'] = $cnt_row;

Comment: if you put the num_row outside the foreach  how you can assign the value to each row?

Comment: i tried to launch the print_r($cnt_row); command and $readyForExport['num_row'] = $cnt_row; outside the loop. the csv is safe but in the row column the values are all the same... it prints " 4 " all the time...

Comment: then it means that I can not understand your problem .. shortly I delete the answer because it seems completely useless

Comment: it is not useless beacause i think we are close to the goal

Comment: but the code  check for $match_id == $value['id_order']  when not equal the row_cnt is set to 1  .then i don't understand why you have 4

Comment: I don't know. by the way I have not understood completely why you set $match_id = -1;

Comment: i put the if loop outside the foreach like this and the result is 1 all the time.                 if ( $match_id == $readyForExport['id_order']){
                       $cnt_row++;
                    } else {
                       $cnt_row =1;
                       $match_id  = $readyForExport['id_order'];
                    } 

                $readyForExport['num_row'] = $cnt_row;

Comment: i have put  $match_id = -1:;  (but i have also change with  $match_id = ''; because for access  to var this must be a value  and is the initila value  (different from each others id_order .. so you can check also the first value ..

Comment: outside the loop the result is always 1 because you don't increment the cnt for each row

Comment: i moved $cnt_row = 0;  and  $match_id = -1;  inside the foreach loop and the result is 1 all the time... i think that the problem is that $match_id = -1; is not correct . we should compare $value['id_order'] with himself from pair to pair

Comment: ...  is just an initialization  .. and you each time the value change must reinit ..  and set the cnt to the start value

Comment: i set $match_id = 0; and now prints 13 all the time. don't know what to say

Comment: could be i don't understand your question and your code and as   i suggested  before  .. in few minute a delete my answer so . you can try to re-eval you question  .

Comment: isn't more usefull to share the problem to some one else at this state of developing ? i think that the construct is correct but we are not matching something right. we are close i think.

Comment: juts the last  shot .. update you question and add  the code you actully are using  ... and sample of the actual result  .

Comment: many thanks scaisEdge , I've edited the question with the actual code and screenshot of the result

Comment: the value of 4  is referrerd to the inner  print_r($cnt_row);  or to the outer $readyForExport['num_row'] = $cnt_row; ???

Comment: to the outer $readyForExport['num_row'] = $cnt_row;  meabe is incorrect ?

Comment: how many fields  you have in each $allexportfields ??  could  be that each $allexportfields   in an array of 4 fields?

Comment: $allexportfields has more than 4 fiels, i paste an array with some of these fiels and some i added before the foreach loop:                 $index_arr=array("id_customer","date_add","ORCL","product_name","causale","product_quantity","G","delivery_date","id_order","J","K","L","M","N","num_row","P","Q","R");

Comment: I dont think its a multi dimensional array beacause $readyForExport[$value] is a field one by one.

Comment: but the inner print_r show the dinamic change for cnt?? .. (could be that 4 is the result for last row)