# php count occurences of an array field and increment the value of another field to print rows associated to ID

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach, count

Hello everybody Im getting headache at this question here [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359589/php-count-array-rows-with-same-id) then I try now to solve in other way.  Ihave a script that loops an array that put data in a CSV file, i need to count the rows with same ID and put the row number line by line.

this is my scritpt that loops the array and put it in a csv file for export.

```
public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
{
    if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
    {
        //one ready for export product
        $readyForExport = array();

            //put in correct sort order
            foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
            {
                $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
                $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);

            }
                //write into csv line by line
        fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
    }
}
```

Is its possible to use array_count_values(); to count the occurences of $value['id_order'] and increment a variable line by line ? when $value['id_order'] changes we must reset to 1.

the result sould exit like this exportet to csv file:

```
 order_ID num_row
```

```
176 1
177 1
177 2
178 1
178 2
179 1
179 2
180 1
181 1
181 2
182 1
182 2
183 1
184 1
184 2
185 1
185 2
186 1
186 2
186 3
```

Many thanks to everyone.

EDIT 
I have edited the code as suggested by Nigel Ren, it seems to be a good solution but I think I'm missing something. Still does not print anything in my variable...

```
            //one ready for export product
        $readyForExport = array();

            //put in correct sort order
            foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
            {
                $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
                $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);

            //$dati_csv = $readyForExport[$value];
            //echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('$dati_csv')</script>";
            }


            $orders = array();
            $orders = $readyForExport['id_order'];
            $lastOrder = null;    // Variable to track previous order
            $orderLine = null;    // the line number added

            foreach ( $orders as &$order )   {
                // If first time round or the order_ID isn't the same as last time
                 if ( $lastOrder === null || $lastOrder != $order["order_ID"])   {
                    $orderLine = 1;
                    $lastOrder = $order["order_ID"];
                    }
                // Add in the orderLine column
                $order['orderLine'] = $orderLine++;
            }
            print_r($orders);

            $readtForExport['num_row'] = $orderds;
```

EDIT 
I Put the fopen(); function where it writes to file as asked by Nigel:

```
public function writeToFile($ae, $sorted_fields, $elements)
{
    $url = $this->getFileUrl($ae->filename, $ae->type);

    $file = @fopen( $url, 'w' );
    //add labels for export data
    if($ae->add_header)
        $this->filewrite($ae, $sorted_fields, $file);

    $i = 0;
    while ($element = $this->nextRow($elements))
    {
        if ($i == $this->rowsNumber - 1)
        {
            $this->lastElement = $element;
        }

        Configuration::updateGlobalValue("AdvancedExport_CURRENT", (string)$i);
        //progress bar
        $this->getDataFromObject($element, $file, $sorted_fields, $ae);
        $i++; //progress bar
    }

    //close file
    if($file)
        fclose($file);

    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all of the orders in the correct order_ID order, you can just keep a track of the last order_id processed and reset a line number when it changes...

```
// A mini set of test data
$orders = [["order_ID" => 1],
        ["order_ID" => 2],
        ["order_ID" => 2],
        ["order_ID" => 3],
        ["order_ID" => 3],
        ["order_ID" => 3],
        ["order_ID" => 4]];


$lastOrder = null;    // Variable to track previous order
$orderLine = null;    // the line number added
foreach ( $orders as &$order )   {
    // If first time round or the order_ID isn't the same as last time
    if ( $lastOrder === null || $lastOrder != $order["order_ID"])   {
        $orderLine = 1;
        $lastOrder = $order["order_ID"];
    }
    // Add in the orderLine column
    $order['orderLine'] = $orderLine++;
}
print_r($orders);
```

This outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_ID] => 1
            [orderLine] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_ID] => 2
            [orderLine] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_ID] => 2
            [orderLine] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [order_ID] => 3
            [orderLine] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [order_ID] => 3
            [orderLine] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [order_ID] => 3
            [orderLine] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [order_ID] => 4
            [orderLine] => 1
        )

)
```

Update:

To keep all of the processing in the `fputToFile()` method, I've resorted to using `static` fields to hold the previous values.  This means that the values will be kept as long as the code is running.  This also means that this may not work if you try and export more than one file at a time.

```
public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
{
    if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
    {
        //one ready for export product
        $readyForExport = array();

        static $lastOrder = null;    // Variable to track previous order
        static $orderLine = null;    // the line number added
        if ( $lastOrder === null || $lastOrder != $allexportfields["order_ID"])   {
            $orderLine = 1;
            $lastOrder = $allexportfields["order_ID"];
        }

        //put in correct sort order
        foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
        {
            $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
            $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);

        }

        // Add in the orderLine column
        $readyForExport[] = $orderLine++;

        //write into csv line by line
        fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Nigel I've edited the code and pasted below I'm missing something but I think yous solution can be good for me. Thanks again.

Comment: I think `fputToFile()` is the wrong place to put this code.  It needs to go before you start to write the file out.  Find where the data is fully loaded but before you start to write it out.

Comment: If you see the $allexportedfields array is cicled and putted into $readyForExport I think the problem is that my code is not written properly my $orders array is missing something I think. not declared clearly as you made in the example.

Comment: Can you add the code where you call `fputToFile()` (should have the `fopen()` code as well), `fputToFile()` looks as though it writes 1 row of the output at a time.  You need to have this code somewhere where you have a list of all of the orders.

Comment: Or meabe I'm not putting $readyForExport['id_order'] data in $orders correctly...

Comment: I've have pasted the function that writes to file above. Can you please check my code of the function that put the orders in another array to see if it's ok ? Many thanks

Comment: Is `while ($element = $this->nextRow($elements))` where it fetches the data and `$element` contains data including the order_ID field?

Comment: probably yes, because I think $elements contains all the data written by the function fputToFile. but I also think we can elaborate data in that position... I'm waiting for you kind reply, thanks again.

Comment: I think we have to work in the fputToFile function because you can see it returns csv string with separetor, data and so on...         //write into csv line by line
        fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);

Comment: nothing changed it does not print anything, im sorry

Comment: I've moved where it adds the order line into the data, can you try this.

Comment: no it prints 1 all the time meabe the if statement must be in foreach loop ?

Comment: I have added // Add in the orderLine column
        $readyForExport['orderLine'] = $orderLine++; to make the code correct but still prints 1 alla the time. seems that the variabile is not taking the if elaboration i think

Comment: A major concern I have is that `fputToFile()` looks as though it is a generic routine and changing that will affect other things which you aren't testing.  So really not sure you should be changing this routine.

Comment: Michael Eugen Yuen helped me in this way I think we are close to the goal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359589/php-count-array-rows-with-same-id/49375732?noredirect=1#comment85795780_49375732